# Hive: Ignore field in create table

Tags: json, hive, hiveql, presto, amazon-athena

I have to load data in json format into hive. Problem is there exists a field which is a date which is different per record leading to all kinds of problems. The DDL for one record looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `not_really_awesome_table` (
  `super_wtf`         struct<
    `10-02-2019`:        string
  >
  `super_blah`        struct <
    `bleh`:             string,
    `blah`:             string,
    `sub_blah`:         struct <
      `blah_field`:       string,
      `bleh_field`:       string
    >
  >
)
ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties ( 'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true' )
LOCATION
  's3://wtf/is/this/lol'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1539066055')
;
```

Is there a way to ignore the `super-wtf` field or cast it into some type which would avoid parsing it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip `super-wtf` column in the DDL and add everything else:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `not_really_awesome_table` (
  `super_blah`        struct <
    `bleh`:             string,
    `blah`:             string,
    `sub_blah`:         struct <
      `blah_field`:       string,
      `bleh_field`:       string
    >
  >
)
```

In this case it will not be parsed from JSON.

Or alternatively define `super-wtf` column as `map<string, string>` in the DDL

Comment: Confirmed, i anyway defined `super-wtf` as a map<string,string> and it worked. Thanks a ton!